# Magento 2 grid column filtering by datetime

Tags: php, magento2

In my grid I have the following

```
     $this->addColumn('end_date', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('End Date'),
        'align'     => 'right',
        'width'     => '150px',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
        'format'    => \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
        'index'     => 'end_date',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callbackColumnEndTime')
    ));
```

It filters datetime value only by date, ignoring time. In magento DateTime filter there is method _convertDate which magento using to filter my datetime, however it always calls return parent::_convertDate($date) and filters it just by date, ignoring time, because of $this->getColumn()->getFilterTime() returning null. My question is how do I filter by datetime, not just by date. I'm assuming that there is some option in addColumn to do this (maybe it'll call setFilterTime($timePart) behind the scenes).

```
    protected function _convertDate($date)
    {
       if ($this->getColumn()->getFilterTime()) {
           try {
               $timezone = $this->getColumn()->getTimezone() !== false
                   ? $this->_localeDate->getConfigTimezone() : 'UTC';
               $adminTimeZone = new \DateTimeZone($timezone);
               $simpleRes = new \DateTime($date, $adminTimeZone);
               $simpleRes->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
               return $simpleRes;
           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               return null;
           }
       }
       return parent::_convertDate($date);
    }
```